# XSLT grouping by unique element values?

Tags: xslt

For my original XML, I have something like:

```
<Data>
  <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type A</Type>
    <Key>Cases</Key>
    <Value>3</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
    <Title>PHYSICIAN DETAIL TOTAL</Title>
    <Type>Type A</Type>
    <Key>Percentage</Key>
    <Value>75.0%</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type B</Type>
    <Key>Cases</Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type B</Type>
    <Key>Percentage</Key>
    <Value>25.0%</Value>
   </Statistic>
</Data>
```

Basically, for each Type, there will only be one "Cases" and one "Percentage". 
The final XML will look like:

```
<Data>
  <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type A</Type>
    <count>
      <Case>1</Case>
      <Percentage>75%</Percentage>
    </count>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type B</Type>
    <count>
       <Case>1</Case>
       <Percentage>25%</Percentage>
    </count>
  </Statistic>
</Data>
```

What's the best way to achieve this?  XSLT group by?

Comment: For `<Type>Type A</Type>`, why should it pick `<Title>Total Values</Title>`, and not `<Title>PHYSICIAN DETAIL TOTAL</Title>`?

Comment: Shouldn't the Case value for Type A be 3? Why do you have it as 1 in the listing of the expected output?

Comment: You've said that "for each Type, there will only be one "Cases" and one "Percentage"". Presumably, by that you mean that there will always be PRECISELY ONE Case and ONE Percentage child of Statistic? That is to say it should not be possible for a Statistic element to have either 0 or 2 Case children? Please confirm.

Comment: @Jon Can you accept one of the answers please?

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="stat-key" match="/Data/Statistic" use="Type"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/Data/Statistic[generate-id()=generate-id(key('stat-key',Type)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="Type"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Statistic">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Title|Type"/>
            <count>
                <Case>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('stat-key', Type)[Key='Cases']/Value"/>
                </Case>
                <Percentage>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('stat-key', Type)[Key='Percentage']/Value"/>
                </Percentage>
            </count>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It picks the `Title` of the first `Statistic` for each `Type`-group.

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
   <Statistic>
      <Title>Total Values</Title>
      <Type>Type A</Type>
      <count>
         <Case>3</Case>
         <Percentage>75.0%</Percentage>
      </count>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
      <Title>Total Values</Title>
      <Type>Type B</Type>
      <count>
         <Case>1</Case>
         <Percentage>25.0%</Percentage>
      </count>
   </Statistic>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP appears to be saying that there is precisely one Case child per Statistic, and precisely one Percentage child per per Statistic. This being the case, grouping is not necessary, and the solution becomes trivial.

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet (also works for XSLT 2.0)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Statistic[Key='Percentage']" />

<xsl:template match="Statistic">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Key|self::Value)]"/>
     <count>
       <Case><xsl:value-of select="Value" /></Case>
       <Percentage><xsl:value-of select=
         "../Statistic[Type=current()/Type][Key='Percentage']/Value" />
       </Percentage>
     </count>   
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to this document...**

```
<Data>
  <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type A</Type>
    <Key>Cases</Key>
    <Value>3</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
    <Title>PHYSICIAN DETAIL TOTAL</Title>
    <Type>Type A</Type>
    <Key>Percentage</Key>
    <Value>75.0%</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type B</Type>
    <Key>Cases</Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type B</Type>
    <Key>Percentage</Key>
    <Value>25.0%</Value>
   </Statistic>
</Data>
```

**...yields...**

```
<Data>
  <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type A</Type>
    <count>
      <Case>3</Case>
      <Percentage>75.0%</Percentage>
    </count>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Title>Total Values</Title>
    <Type>Type B</Type>
    <count>
      <Case>1</Case>
      <Percentage>25.0%</Percentage>
    </count>
  </Statistic>
</Data>
```